# Working with Facebook Connect

Tags: facebook

I have two files with identical code (it is the code they mention here: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/198).  I have one of these files here: http://gnucom.cc/test.html and another one of these files here: http://blog.gnucom.cc/test.html.  I have the main URL set to `gnucom.cc` and the Connect URL set to `http://blog.gnucom.cc`.

For the life of me, I cannot figure out why the version accessed from the subdomain doesn't work.  I receive a loading icon and that is it - afterwards it disappears.

Can anyone suggest what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Supporting_Subdomains_In_Facebook_Connect

You should type in http://gnucom.cc instead of http://www.gnucom.cc (if it's not already this way)

Comment: Okay, great, this did fix the problem I was having (I switched http://blog.gnucom.cc to http://gnucom.cc).  However, the feature still doesn't show up in my blog URL when the path is something like http://blog.gnucom.cc/2010/some-post, rather, it only works when the path is exactly at http://blog.gnucom.cc/, is this another setting I must address somewhere?

Comment: FB.init("377853f30c64021c8463a55a0d86e273", "xd_receiver.htm");
to
FB.init("377853f30c64021c8463a55a0d86e273", "/xd_receiver.htm");